# How to keep track of objectives in X3: Reunion

Tags: x3-reunion

I recently picked up X3: Reunion and have been enjoying it. However with the lack of a proper tutorial most of my time has been spent figuring things out. I know the game is rather huge and allows you to go off on your own so one thing I'm afraid of is losing track of plot objectives. I know I usually get a message telling me where to go but it seems like I'm getting lots of messages in the beginning and I'm worried about losing it if I go off on my own or take a long break between gaming sessions. Is there a menu or something that keeps track of current mission objectives? I didn't see one during my beginning missions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time with no answers and being unable to find one myself (and mostly having not played the game a ton) I'd have to say there is no in game way of doing it. I have heard important plot npc characters will send you a message or something if you don't do anything with the plot in awhile but can't really confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a dedicated mission log. As you mentioned, mission messages will be saved to your general message log. Not entirely ideal as it gets cluttered fast.

Another game-y method would be to hail somebody - either someone on a station, or a random passing ship. You will get an option : "How do I get to *X*?"

X will be where you'll need to head next in your mission.